# Best way to store math calculations to mysql db

Tags: mysql, math, types, formula, sqldatatypes

I'm just trying to save history of calculations made by calculator app to the mysql db.
I can't figure out how to perform this. 
Do I need to use any specific data type or break the calculations into the pieces and store them separately for further reassembling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly understand what you try to acheive. can you post an example of code, or give more explanations?

```
CREATE TABLE history
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  calculation TEXT,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO history (calculation)
VALUES
('2+2=4'),
('1+1=2'),
('4+5=9');
```

...

Comment: you understood it right. I need to save those values: ('2+2=4'),
('1+1=2'),
('4+5=9'); and I also need to fetch them not just like text, but as integers and math operators in order to be able to analyze this calculations. that's why using text data type looks as inappropriate for me.

Comment: Can't you just parse them after fetching? You could create somekind of `Computation` object in your program and then serialize it into JSON string and still store it as text. After fetching you could deserialize string into Computation object and keep working with it

Comment: agree, thank you, it looks the best way for me too. just thought there could be some pattern I am not aware of for this purpose. thanks!